# Javascript: possible for parent to kill child iframe if it is stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, iframe, infinite-loop

I have a page that has an iframe with external content.  I don't want infinite loops in the external content to crash my whole page.  Is there any way to get around this.

I tried to set something up where the parent postMessages the child iframe every so often and if the child Iframe doesn't respond for too long a time the parent changes the iframes src, but this doesn't seem to work.  The parent's setTimeout functions no longer execute once the iframe starts looping.  See my code here (note that it will crash your tab if you execute it, open the console before execution to view the logging):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var scr = 'script';
var html = '<html><head><script>\n' +
'  window.addEventListener("message", answer, false);' +
'  function answer() { console.log("answered"); parent.postMessage(\'hi\', \'*\');}' +
'  setTimeout("while(1){console.log(\'in loop\')};", 3000)' +
"</" + scr + "></head><body>IFRAME</body</html>";

var lastAnswer = (new Date()).getTime();
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
queryChild();

window.addEventListener("message", receive, false);
function receive() {
  lastAnswer = (new Date()).getTime();
  console.log('got answer');
}

function queryChild() {
  console.log('querying');
  if((new Date()).getTime() - lastAnswer > 5000) {
    console.log('killing');
    iframe.src = '';
  } else if(iframe.contentWindow){
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('hi', '*');
  }
  setTimeout(queryChild, 2000);
};

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My experience with this kind of problem is that unless you can access the external code before feeding it to the `iframe` (either as an URL or via the [srcdoc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe) attribute), the loop will completely interrupt any JavaScript execution.

Whatever kind of timeout functionality you implement, it will not be called due to the iframe code execution consuming 100% resources until the browser reports a crash.

Your options are:

- **Sanitize the code automatically** before adding it to the `iframe`, which proves impractical since there are infinite ways to loop infinitely, and you will not be able to catch them all. You would have to write a scanner script that could detect infinite loops while not crashing in the course of scanning the code.
- Use a **sandboxing solution like [Google Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/)** to sanitize the code. However, this will change the code structurally if not configured heavily.
- In case of an application that has capabilites of **creating virtual environments** and monitoring them, you could execute the iframe code (let's say on a virtual machine of sorts), check if the process locks up and use that outcome to determine if you can safely set the `iframe.src` property to your code's URL. This might be the only solution that can guarantee some sort of guarantee that this code will not lock up immediately (however, there are many ways to have race conditions at some later point of execution, so there will not be a sure way to say it will never lock up the browser).

**Summary**: Unless you can find a way to test the code extensively before showing it in the `iframe`, you can not guarantee that the iframe code will not lock up the browser tab.

Comment: I think this is the most complete answer, not was I was hoping for obviously but informative

Comment: Thanks, and I must say that I have walked in your shoes when I was looking for a solution to that problem a while ago. You would assume that this problem has been tackled by someone before, but it seems that many people assume that no infinite loops will ever find their way into the iframe. Now that I think of it, there may even be a mathematical proof to the argument that no software whatsoever will be  able to determine with absolute success if a particular piece of code will ever not loop forever. `eval` and its derivatives come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

It depends highly on the browser, some browser uses one thread for each page (or iframe), in this case your script cannot be executed until the iframe execution is over (the infinite loop). Some others have one thread per page (or iframe) and maybe you are able to do it.

What I'm sure is than if you expect to support enterprise browsers (like IE8) you can't.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
console.log('killing');
    iframe.src = '';
```

Will not kill the `iframe`. according to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you can not manipulate external domains from your domain. Just changing the `src` of an `iframe` doesn't trigger a navigation in the `iframe`. `src` will change, but `iframe` will not get navigated.

If your get the message from inner `iframe` you should remove the `iframe` from your document tree and insert a new one in document tree in order to *kill* the iframe using `removeChild`

```
document.body.removeChild(iframe);
document.body.appendChild(newiframe);
```

Look at this simple demonstration I've created here: http://jsbin.com/avodeb/1/

Comment: that is helpful, however unfortunately the queryChild function just stops being called once the inner iframe starts looping.

Comment: My solution to your problem wouldn't involve iframes. When you have document content why not to use a `documentFragment` to build your document node based on HTML string you already have?

Comment: The HTML string has JS in it including potentially DOM manipulations.  My understanding is that document fragments cannot execute these, but I am very inexperienced with documentFragments, am I incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('iframeID').onload= function() { //When the iframe loads quickly
     clearTimeout(killerTimer); // Stop the Killer Timer
 };
 var killerTimer = setTimeout( function() {
     document.getElementById("iframeID").setAttribute("src",""); //Otherwise, kill the iframe
 }, 3000 ); 
</script>
```

Comment: The problem with this kind of solution is that once the iframe is looping indefinitely, it will not even reach the timeout function, the whole page locks in that event (in my case both for Chrome and Firefox, tested with an iframe that executes `while (true){}`). Have you ever implemented this successfully?

Comment: This only works when placed before the iFrame. Otherwise, the chosen answer is well put and more detailed than mine.